# MVC: передача из контроллера HTML-кода в представление

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добрый день.

В контроллере я генерирую HTML (string), который потом передаю в представление посредством "

> ViewBag.MatrixCode = htmlMatrixCode; // .....

"

Код представление:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Поворот матрицы на 90 градусов";
}

<div>
    <h2>@ViewData["MatrixCode"].</h2>
</div>
```

В итоге я вижу в теге div вместо таблицы текст, содержимое переменной @ViewData["MatrixCode"].

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отобразить тут в представлении таблицу, а не ее html-текст?**

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

```
<h2>@Html.Raw(ViewData["MatrixCode"]).</h2>
```

Comment: Второй вариант - передавать не string, а IHtmlString.